# Is OpenSSL required to build the PoDoFo library?

Tags: podofo

I am trying to build PoDoFo (0.9.3) for Windows using Visual C++ 2008 Express.  Is OpenSSL required for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add your OpenSSL directory manually to the include directories of PoDoFo project.

Comment: Download from OpenSSL page is showing many errors. May I use binaries from gnuwin32? If yes than these binaries only have .dll files. From where I will get header files to manually include?

Comment: I don't use precompiled binaries but I guess you can. As for the header files, just download specific OpenSSL version source and extract the `include` directory.

Comment: I need to copy .dll files in lib folder of openSSL. right?

Comment: You can copy the .dlls wherever you like, as long as you link them properly in your project settings.

Comment: When I follow Readme.txt of PoDoFo it asks us to build libjpeg using Visual Studio. In the resulting folder there is no entry for include or lib folder but build.cmd mentions them. So, does it mean that I have to manually copy all header files in a created include folder and dll etc in lib folder?

Comment: You may certainly try, as I'm not sure what is exactly the problem.

Comment: Hi Lesny. Have you built PoDoFo using Cmake and Visual studio? I am getting following errors. Looking for strings.h
 Looking for strings.h - not found
 Looking for arpa/inet.h
 Looking for arpa/inet.h - not found
 Looking for winsock2.h
 Looking for winsock2.h - found
 Looking for mem.h
 Looking for mem.h - not found
 Looking for ctype.h
 Looking for ctype.h - found
 Looking for sys/types.h
 Looking for sys/types.h - found
 Looking for stdint.h
 Looking for stdint.h - not found
 Looking for BaseTsd.h
 Looking for BaseTsd.h - found
 Looking for sys/types.h
 Looking for sys/types.h - found

Comment: Hi Lesny. Do you know how to compile and build OpenSSL for Microsoft Visual C++?

Comment: Sure. Follow the instructions in INSTALL.W32 file, under `Visual C++` section.

Comment: I am using 7-zip to extract the source code in Windows. But its giving 33 errors. Do you know any other way to extract the code.

Comment: You can use Total Commander for file management and extraction.

Comment: Hi Lesney. I am getting following error. Though I set windows environment path. NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'ms\ntdll.mak' not found
Stop.

Comment: Having so many problems you should create a new question which specifically focuses on a single problem - compiling OpenSSL in your case. Though it appears you didn't follow the instructions properly `perl Configure VC-WIN32` followed by `ms\do_nasm` should give you `ntdll.mak` all right.